# How to Write a DAG with Multiple Similar Tasks

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to move data from 50 tables in Postgres to BigQuery via Airflow. Each table follows the same 4 operations, just on different data:

```
get_latest_timestamp >> copy_data_to_bigquery >> verify_bigquery_data >> delete_postgres_data
```

#### What's the cleanest way to repeat these operations for 50 tables?

Some things I've considered:

- Make a DAG for each table

  - Is there a way to make a "DAG of DAGs?" I may want `table 1` to process before `table 2`, for example. I know I can use [cross-DAG dependencies](https://blog.damavis.com/en/advanced-airflow-cross-dag-task-and-sensor-dependencies/) to achieve a similar effect, but I'd like to have a "main DAG" which manages these relationships.
- Write out the 200 tasks (ugly, I know) in a single DAG, then do something like

```
get_latest_timestamp_table1 >> copy_data_to_bigquery_table1 >> verify_bigquery_data_table1 >> delete_postgres_data_table1
get_latest_timestamp_table2 >> copy_data_to_bigquery_table2 >> verify_bigquery_data_table2 >> delete_postgres_data_table2
...
```

- Looping inside the main DAG (not sure if this is possible), something like

```
for table in table_names:
    get_latest_timestamp = {PythonOperator with tablename as an input}
    ...
    get_latest_timestamp >> copy_data_to_bigquery >> verify_bigquery_data >> delete_postgres_data
```

Any other ideas? I'm pretty new to Airflow, so not sure what the best practices are for repeating similar operations.

I tried copy/pasting each task (50*4=200 tasks) in a single DAG. It works, but is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid code replication you could use TaskGroups. This is very well described [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups)

```
for table in table_names:
with TaskGroup(group_id='process_tables') as process_tables:
    get_latest_timestamp = EmptyOperator(task_id=f'{table}_timestamp')
    copy_data_to_bigquery = EmptyOperator(task_id=f'{table}_to_bq')
    .....
    get_latest_timestamp >> copy_data_to_bigquery
```

You can fetch xcoms by providing also the task group like so: '''

> process_tables.copy_data_to_bigquery

Combining task group with other task would look like this

> start >> process_tables >> end